# Live Reload (Blaise Kal) Firefox add-on doesn't work with a CSS file

Tags: firefox, yii2, firefox-addon, livereload

I want to use [Live Reload add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/live-reload) to monitor changes in my `persons.css` file. But when I modify the code of my CSS file nothing changes in my Firefox.

The address that I use is like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/persons/person?id=1
```

It shows a HTML page that loads my simple `persons.css` file.

This is the configuration that I have:

[image: Configuration]

I use this add-on becuse has good stars but I can use another one. It is the first live reload that I use in a Yii2 project.

Answer (score 0):

From the Developers of the Addon, within the reviews section of the plugin:

> Local files cannot be monitored due to security restrictions in web
> extensions, enforced by Firefox.
>
> In your case, I guess .tpl and .php files are used to render a page
> that's served on http://localhost? Can you use localhost URLs to set
> up a reload rule?
>
> Note that in Live Reload, a Host can monitor itself. Example:
>
> Host URL: http://localhost/some/path/*
>
> Source file URLs http://localhost/some/path/*

Not sure if this is still ALL applicable, as the plugin seems to run ok, if the Host URLs and Source Urls match.